why does my package manager console stop running?
This problem occurs to me every now and then. I use visual studio 2022, .NET 7.0 and I have installed these NUGET Packages:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (7.0.2)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (7.0.2)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (7.0.2)

I have run package manager console for many times without any problem.
For some reason sometimes I delete the migration folder and the database made by  the migration and then re-Add-Migration initialMig and it usually works with no difficulties but after a while of some migration remove, the PMC doesn't proceed to complete the Migration. The build is okey! The VS 2022 doesn't freeze! Only PMC freezes and I need to re-start the project so that I can try out the Add-Migration one more time.
Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> add-migration FirstMigration
Build started...
Build succeeded.

The only way I could have dealt with this issue was to copy + paste all of the codes in a new project and then it works and the Migration is successfully added! But it's both annoying and time consuming! I have searched for the solution but in other questions there was at least an error. I encounter not a single error! It's as the PMC loses its vital signs after Build succeeded!
I'd be grateful if anyone here could help me out with this problem.

It may be due to cache issues. You can try to clean up the NuGet cache: use the Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings menu command, then select Clear All NuGet Cache(s). Then check if there are any Extensions installed in the project. If so, try disabling them and try again. Finally, if the problem persists,you can consider repairing VS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Did you try using dotnet ef tool?

@YuningDuan I tried all of your solutions. I selected Clear All NuGet Storage (not Cache), disabled extensions, and repaired VS, But none of them worked :( Any other Idea?? Do I have to copy-paste my project into a new one again?!

@MichałTurczyn I don't know. What's that? I have installed the NuGet Package: EFCore.Tools, but I'm not sure you mean that.

dotnet is command line tool
